# How to use PHP(5.5) extract EXIF(version 2.3) info from JPEG file

Tags: php, laravel, exif, intervention

I am now using PHP v5.5.30, in its information page:

> exif
>
> EXIF Support  enabled
>
> EXIF Version  1.4 $Id:a0425de51ec3270d01522bf62d41bfe78893f78d $
>
> Supported EXIF Version    0220
>
> Supported filetypes   JPEG,TIFF

When I use `exit()` function of ``(actually use php native function) to retrieve exif info from jpeg, it always give some wrong results:

```
  "Make" => "\x01"
  "Model" => null
  "Orientation" => 1
```

How can I solve this problem? Is there any way that I can let php support EXIF v2.3 or any 3rd party library?

Many thanks.

Comment: What should the output be? Which EXIF version is your jpeg using? Do you have the jpeg online so we could download it to try for ourselves?

Comment: @Tim  
"Make" should be 'Canon' and Model is 'EOS 650D', EXIF version is V2.3 here is a sample picture static.ileodo.com/test_exif.jpg